# Vertx: How to forward messages from one verticle to another with deliveryoptions?

Tags: vert.x

I send a message to one verticle which in turn might need to forward it to other verticles. I don't want to write redundant code to copy headers from the message and create another message object and pass it. Is there a way to forward the message in vert.x with deliveryOptions intact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not exactly possible, but if you are only interested in headers it is pretty straightforward to forward. You can set the headers in one single method call. You cannot however forward the entire message object by passing it to the send method.

This works for me.

```
vertx.eventBus().send("forwardingAddress",
                    message.body(),new DeliveryOptions()
                        .setHeaders(message.headers()));
```

Comment: This doesn't work unless you pass the reply address in the headers.

Answer (score 0):

> Using DeliveryOptions you can transfer messages in between Verticles.

Consider following example :

// MainVerticle will be receiving data and we will be sending to MessagingVerticle

```
 public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

 @Override
 public void start(Future<Void> fut) {
  //your logic goes here for message object to pass
   MessageConsumer<Object> mc = vertx.eventBus().consumer("your_addressToServer").handler(message -> {

   Object message =  message.body(); 

    final DeliveryOptions options = new DeliveryOptions().setCodecName("any_messaging_address_name");
    vertx.eventBus().send("any_messaging_address_name", Object(message object to pass) , options);

   });

 }

}
```

// Send those messages to MessagingVerticle

```
public class MessagingVerticle   extends AbstractVerticle {

@Override
public void start(Future<Void> fut) {
    vertx.eventBus().<Object>consumer("any_messaging_address_name",
            message -> {
                Object messageCommand = message.body(); // received object from MainVerticle                
            });
    fut.complete();
  }

}
```

> I hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still don't understand how this would help me achieve forwarding messages with headers intact.

Comment: you can use `message.headers()` to retrieve a header from response body and use it as you want.

Comment: Yes, I can do that. Actually I want to forward the message without copying all headers and other meta information at each point in forwarding, as I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: So you can simply forward message object.

Comment: Can I do that? I tried to do it and failed. I had to copy headers and other meta info into DeliveryOptions. It doesn't send headers if I simply forward it.

Comment: I have the same issue. @RonakVyas Were you able to solve this?